# Meteor: Get data to use on sub templates

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

This is how I try to display an article as user and editor view. I don't use any router, so I do the subscribe at `onCreated`.

But I don't like it to do for title and content a findOne(). I think I can get the complete data in one find-request and use this data in both templates (user/editor). But how should I do that?

**templates**

```
<template name="example">
    {{#if isEditorView}}
        {{ > editor }}
    {{else}}
        {{ > user }}
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="editor">
    <input type="text" placeholder="title" value="{{title}}">
    <textarea placeholder="article">{{content}}</textarea>
</template>

<template name="user">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    {{{content}}}
</template>
```

**helpers**

```
Template.example.onCreated(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('articles');
});

Template.example.helpers({
    isEditorView: function() { 
        return Session.get('editorView') ? true : false; 
    },

    title: function() {
        var doc = Collection.findOne();
        return doc.title;
    },

    content: function(plain) {
        var doc = Collection.findOne();
        return doc.content; 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{{#with }}` to set the data context:

```
<template name="example">
{{#with doc}}
  {{#if isEditorView}}
    {{ > editor }}
  {{else}}
    {{ > user }}
  {{/if}}
{{/with}}
</template>
```

Then you only need one helper:

```
Template.example.helpers({
  isEditorView: function() { 
    return Session.get('editorView') ? true : false; 
  },
  doc: function() {
    return Collection.findOne();
  }
});
```